# Get unique keys found in the second level of a 2d array and sum the total number of occurrences

Tags: php, arrays, count, key, associative-array

Let's say I have an array like this:

```
$array = [
   ['a' => 'v', 'b' => 's', 'c' => 's'],
   ['c' => 's', 'd' => 's', 'b' => 's'],
   ['b' => 's', 'e' => 's', 'g' => 's'],
];
```

I want to create a new array which contains how many unique keys are found anywhere in my array's associative rows.

Desired result:

```
[
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 3,
    'c' => 2,
    'd' => 1,
    'e' => 1,
    'g' => 1
]
```

I tried with `array_count_values()`, but it is not right for my array structure.

Answer (score 1):

Some correction and addition to your answer.

```
$newArray = Array();
foreach ($array as $values) {
    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        if (!isset($newArray[$key]))     
            $newArray[$key] = 0;          // create new 0 element
        $newArray[$key]++;  
    }
}
```

Other functional approach

```
$result = array_count_values( // 3. count values
            call_user_func_array('array_merge', // 2. merge array of keys
                    array_map('array_keys', $array))); // 1. convert inner array to array with keys
var_dump($result);
```

Second one, just replace loops with `array_map`

```
$result = array();
array_map(function($inner_array)use(&$result)
    {
    array_map(function($key)use(&$result)
        {
        $value = &$result[$key];              // reference trick
        $value++;
        }, array_keys($inner_array));
    }, $array);
var_dump($result);
```

Third one, with array_reduce

```
$result = array_count_values(
    array_reduce($array, function($result, $inner_array)
        {
        return array_merge($result, array_keys($inner_array)); // merge arrays one by one
        }, []));

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some alternative and modernized techniques not mentioned by @sectus.

Codes: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/UCgKX))

1. Functional-style with spread-flattening:

   ```
   var_export(
       array_count_values(
           array_merge(
               ...array_map(
                   'array_keys',
                   $array
               )
           )
       )
   );
   ```
2. Classic nested loops with null coalescing operator:

   ```
   $counts = [];
   foreach ($array as $row) {
       foreach ($row as $k => $v) {
           $counts[$k] = ($counts[$k] ?? 0) + 1;
       }
   }
   var_export($counts);
   ```
3. Recursive iteration to access only leaf-nodes:

   ```
    $counts = [];
    array_walk_recursive($array, function($v, $k) use(&$counts) {
        $counts[$k] = ($counts[$k] ?? 0) + 1;
    });
    var_export($counts);
   ```

Answer (score -1):

I do that, it is working, but i want to know if exists another method:

```
$newArray = Array();
foreach ($array as $values) {
    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        $newArray[$key]++;  
    }
}
```